# Change value of controlled input in React

Tags: reactjs, input, state

I'm looking for some help on React controlled/uncontrolled/controllable inputs.

Here's a diagram to explain:

[React Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fvCi.jpg)

As you can see in the image, I have two components:

- The Slider component: A ranged input from 0 to 50000.
- The second component is a text input. Currently this is read only and displays the value of the slider.

**What I want to do**

- The text input is currently a *controlled component*. Instead I would like to make it so the user can type into the text box. If the added text is both a number and between 0 to 50,000, the slider state value would update to the typed text input value.

Here's my code:

```
  state = {
    sliderValue: 10000
  }

handleChangeSlider = value => {
    this.setState({
      sliderValue: value
    })
  }


<Slider
min={5000}
max={45000}
step={250}
value={this.state.sliderValue}
onChange={this.handleChangeSlider}
/>

<input
className={amountInput}
value={this.state.sliderValue}
/>
```

One possible solution to this I have thought of, is to overlay a new 'filter' input over the controlled input. Thereby there is two inputs, one to display the slider value and one to input a new value.

I feel like I am missing something here.

Is there anyone who can guide me down the right track?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the problem now? Does the slider change the value of input and does the input change the value of slider?

Comment: Right now, the text input isn't editable. If I make it editable by removing the value attribute and setting a defaultValue instead, the problem is that the text input no longer follows the value of this.state.sliderValue.

If I keep the value attribute however, then the input is not editable, which means that input can't be used to input a new slider value

Comment: Add `onChange`  to your input, `<input className={amountInput} onChange={this.handleChangeSlider} />`

Comment: Thanks @seethrough. I tried this. The input still displays the slider value. However the input value is still not editable and when I press any key, the value changes to [object Object]

Comment: Ok, I see. The answer is a bit complicated to fit into comment, I will ad an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the input editable try the following:

```
handleInput = event => {
  this.setState({sliderValue: event.target.value})
} 

<input className={amountInput} value={this.state.sliderValue} onChange={this.handleInput}/>
```

and don't forget to bind handleInput in your constructor.

Don't hesitate to comment if anything goes wrong with this piece of code.

Comment: @Barney I have sent you an email. Thanks.